# JS Canvas, drawing random squares using 2D arrays

Tags: javascript, canvas, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a replication of John Conway's game of life, and I am working on making a functional 2D array that can retrieve if the cell is dead or alive, however, when attempting to draw the first 10 random cells on the screen, instead of drawing 10 random cells, my code draws 10 random lines. The code I am using is the following:

```
let board;
let context;

const cellAmount = 100;
let cellSize;

const numOfSpawn = 10;

var cell = [[],[]];

function createBoard(){
    board.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    board.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight

    if (board.height < board.width){
        cellSize = Math.floor(board.height/cellAmount);
    } else {
        cellSize = Math.floor(board.width/cellAmount);
    }

    let iVertical = 0;
    for (iVertical; iVertical * cellSize < board.height; iVertical++){
        let iHorizontal = 0;
        for(iHorizontal; iHorizontal * cellSize < board.width; iHorizontal++){
            cell[[iHorizontal],[iVertical]] = 0;
        }
    }

    let i = 0;
    for (i; i < numOfSpawn; i++){
        var randomH = Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.floor((board.clientWidth/cellSize)))
        var randomV = Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.floor((board.clientHeight/cellSize)))
        cell[
            [randomH],
            [randomV]
        ] = 1;
    }
}

function update(){
    board.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    board.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    
    if (board.height < board.width){
        cellSize = Math.floor(board.height/cellAmount);
    } else {
        cellSize = Math.floor(board.width/cellAmount);
    }

    let iVertical = 0;
    for (iVertical; iVertical * cellSize < board.height; iVertical++){
        let iHorizontal = 0;
        for(iHorizontal; iHorizontal * cellSize < board.width; iHorizontal++){
            context.fillStyle = "black";
            context.fillRect(
                iHorizontal * cellSize,
                iVertical * cellSize,
                cellSize,
                cellSize
            )
            if (cell[[iHorizontal],[iVertical]] === 1){    
                context.fillStyle = "white";
                context.fillRect(
                    iHorizontal * cellSize,
                    iVertical * cellSize,
                    cellSize,
                    cellSize
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

window.onload = () => {
    board = document.getElementById("board");
    context = board.getContext("2d");
    createBoard();
    setInterval(update,1000/60)
}
```

I have attempted a couple of things:
I attempted to invert line 61 to `if (cell[[iVertical],[iVertical]] === 1){`, however, that just inverts the horizontal lines onto vertical lines

I have also attempted to make a nested if statement, so the code becomes:

```
if (cell[[iHorizontal],[iVertical]] === 1){    
    if (cell[[iVertical],[iHorizontal]] === 1){   
        context.fillStyle = "white";
        context.fillRect(
            iHorizontal * cellSize,
            iVertical * cellSize,
            cellSize,
            cellSize
        )
    }
}
```

However, both this attempts have been unsuccessful.

Comment: They may appear to be lines, but they are actually a series of rectangles drawn alongside each other.

Comment: Yes, however i don't know why they are behaving like this. Its as if they were locking on to just the iVertical value, without regard for the iHorizontal.

Comment: Main issue - you don't have 100x100 multidimension array, but 2x100 array. I will try to create a working example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is that instead of 100x100 multidimension array you had only 2x100 array. Here is working version, where I added multidimension array initialization and fixed array indexing (a[[i][j] => a[i][j])

```js
let board = {};
let context;

const cellAmount = 100;
let cellSize;

const numOfSpawn = 10;

var cell = [];

function createBoard(){
    board.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    board.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight

    if (board.height < board.width){
        cellSize = Math.floor(board.height/cellAmount);
    } else {
        cellSize = Math.floor(board.width/cellAmount);
    }
    
    // array init
    for (let iHorizontal = 0; iHorizontal * cellSize < board.width; iHorizontal++) {
      cell[iHorizontal] = [];
    }

    let iVertical = 0;
    for (iVertical; iVertical * cellSize < board.height; iVertical++){
        let iHorizontal = 0;
        for(iHorizontal; iHorizontal * cellSize < board.width; iHorizontal++){
            cell[iHorizontal][iVertical] = 0;
        }
    }

    let i = 0;
    for (i; i < numOfSpawn; i++){
        var randomH = Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.floor((board.clientWidth/cellSize)))
        var randomV = Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.floor((board.clientHeight/cellSize)))
        cell[randomH][randomV] = 1;
    }
}

function update(){
    board.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    board.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    
    if (board.height < board.width){
        cellSize = Math.floor(board.height/cellAmount);
    } else {
        cellSize = Math.floor(board.width/cellAmount);
    }
    console.log(cellSize)

    let iVertical = 0;
    for (iVertical; iVertical * cellSize < board.height; iVertical++){
        let iHorizontal = 0;
        for(iHorizontal; iHorizontal * cellSize < board.width; iHorizontal++){
            context.fillStyle = "black";
            context.fillRect(
                iHorizontal * cellSize,
                iVertical * cellSize,
                cellSize,
                cellSize
            )
            if (cell[iHorizontal][iVertical] === 1){    
                context.fillStyle = "white";
                context.fillRect(
                    iHorizontal * cellSize,
                    iVertical * cellSize,
                    cellSize,
                    cellSize
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

window.onload = () => {
    board = document.getElementById("board");
    context = board.getContext("2d");
    createBoard();
    update();
    // setInterval(update,1000/60)
}
```

```html
<canvas style="border: 1px solid red" id="board"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks man, well explained.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an illustration of how your rectangles are being drawn.

```js
let board;
let context;

const cellAmount = 100;
let cellSize;

const numOfSpawn = 10;

var cell = [[],[]];

function createBoard(){
    board.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    board.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight

    if (board.height < board.width){
        cellSize = Math.floor(board.height/cellAmount);
    } else {
        cellSize = Math.floor(board.width/cellAmount);
    }
    
    let iVertical = 0;
    for (iVertical; iVertical * cellSize < board.height; iVertical++){
        let iHorizontal = 0;
        for(iHorizontal; iHorizontal * cellSize < board.width; iHorizontal++){
            cell[[iHorizontal],[iVertical]] = 0;
        }
    }

    let i = 0;
    for (i; i < numOfSpawn; i++){
        var randomH = Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.floor((board.clientWidth/cellSize)))
        var randomV = Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.floor((board.clientHeight/cellSize)))
        cell[
            [randomH],
            [randomV]
        ] = 1;
    }
}

function update(){
    board.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    board.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    if (board.height < board.width){
        cellSize = Math.floor(board.height/cellAmount);
    } else {
        cellSize = Math.floor(board.width/cellAmount);
    }

    let iVertical = 0;
    for (iVertical; iVertical * cellSize < board.height; iVertical++){
        let iHorizontal = 0;
        for(iHorizontal; iHorizontal * cellSize < board.width; iHorizontal++){
            context.fillStyle = "black";
            // only draw if even iVertical && even iHorizontal;
            iVertical % 2 && iHorizontal % 2 && context.fillRect(
                (iHorizontal * cellSize),
                iVertical * cellSize,
                cellSize,
                cellSize
            )

            if (cell[[iHorizontal],[iVertical]] === 1){ 
                context.fillStyle = "white";
                context.fillRect(
                    iHorizontal * cellSize,
                    iVertical * cellSize,
                    cellSize,
                    cellSize
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

window.onload = () => {
    board = document.getElementById("board");
    context = board.getContext("2d");
    createBoard();
    update();
    //setInterval(update,1000/60)
}
```

```html
<canvas style="border: 1px solid red" id="board"></canvas>
```